# App that controls PC's mouse cursor using Android's mouse cursor

Tags: android, mouse, remote-desktop

I have a mouse connected to my mobile via USB.

I want an app that let me control the mouse cursor on my computer using a mouse connected to my Android device without having to touch or drag on the screen to move it, i.e., when I see the mouse cursor move on my Android device, it is also moving on my computer. I don't need a normal app where you use your mobile as a touch pad. I need an app that uses the mouse pointer on my mobile (which appears when I connect a mouse to my mobile) to control the mouse pointer on my computer.

If there is nothing like that, can someone recommend me an open-source PC remote application so I can try to implement this myself? Because it is very hard to make one from scratch.

Comment: Like a line-site-remote-control remote control, without the visual feedback that you would get with a full remote desktop application?

Comment: I don't think i fully understand what you mean by (line-site-remote-control) but i don't care if the app has the visual feedback or not all i want is that the app reads the movement of the mouse pointer on my mobile and make the same movement to the mouse pointer on the computer.

Comment: Just to be clear to others - the OP is not seeking something like TeamViewer. In fact, he doesn't even want to see the PC's screen on his Android device

Comment: Which makes me wonder how far wireless mouses can transmit and whether the Android is even necessary.

Comment: As for an open source application, looks like Synergy fits the bill: https://github.com/symless There's even an Android version now.

Comment: please see: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dmitsoft.mouse

Answer (score 0):

I used to use AndroMouse. You need a client installed on your Windows machine, I don't know if it comes in Linux flavour. I thought the code was [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/andromouse/downloads), but it doesn't look like to be there.

Comment: You probably didn't understand me well.I don't need a normal app where you use your mobile as a touch pad ,I need an app that uses the mouse pointer on my mobile (which appears when i connect a mouse to my mobile) to control the mouse pointer on my computer. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: ohh, no I didn't understand indeed. Sorry about the useless reply